# Как распаковать gzip'ованную строку на стороне браузера в javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Всем привет.

Такая проблема: сервер php отправляет через `ajax` браузеру строку, сжатую с помощью
`gzdeflate()`:

```
$string=gzdeflate($string,9);
echo $string;

В браузере подключён pako.js и выполняется:
var rsp=rst.responseText;
rsp=pako.inflate(rsp);
```

Однако это не работает, и консоль браузера говорит:

> "Uncaught unknown compression method"

(А без компрессии строки и привлечения `pako ajax` работает нормально)

Использование на стороне сервера `base64_encode ($string=base64_encode($string);)` и замена `gzdeflate()` на `gzencode()` дают то же самое.

Как распаковать строку `gzip` в `javascript`?

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Какой `pako`?  Зачем он нужен, сжимайте gzip на стороне сервера, просто отправте брайзеру заголовок:

```
 { 'content-encoding': 'gzip' }
```

Браузер расшифрует сам эту строку без pako!

Comment: Спасибо! Нужно заметить, что заголовок 'content-encoding': 'gzip' работает, только если используется gzencode(). При gzdeflate() ajax по onreadystatechange выдаёт request.status 0 вместо 200.

Comment: разумеется, если сжимать deflate, то надо ставить хеадер  `{'content-encoding':'deflate'}`